# Парсинг JSON в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Хочу разобраться с чего начать парсинг в *Node.js*, то есть какие модули могут помочь в этом.

Есть данные в формате *JSON* такого вида:

```
{
    "id": 4055833268,
    "original_id": 2838729037,
    "defindex": 30140,
    "level": 10,
    "quality": 6,
    "inventory": 3221225475,
    "quantity": 1,
    "origin": 2,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "defindex": 142,
            "value": 1246442696,
            "float_value": 3329330
        },
        {
            "defindex": 261,
            "value": 1246442696,
            "float_value": 3329330
        },
        {
            "defindex": 292,
            "value": 1115684864,
            "float_value": 64
        },
        {
            "defindex": 388,
            "value": 1115684864,
            "float_value": 64
        }
    ]
}
```

Данные получаю по ссылке такого вида (без расширения файла):

```
http://site.com/base/?id=6767657657&key=klj87ui6789yi6789uy
```

Для получения данных по такой ссылке я использовал модуль [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) (может, есть более удобный способ?):

```
var url = 'http://site.com/base/?id=6767657657&key=klj87ui6789yi6789uy',
    file = 'f.json';
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        fs.writeFileSync(file, body);
    }
});
var obj = fs.readFileSync('./f.json','utf8');
var parse = JSON.parse(obj);
```

Данные я хочу парсить в цикле (`for`, `for in`, ...) по условию типа `if (float_value == 3329330)`.

Если условие совпало, то выполняем код дальше (я так понимаю, это синхронный код должен быть), а если нет, то возвращаемся и начинаем парсить сначала через определенный промежуток времени.

Возможно, есть удобный вариант сделать парсер на другом языке, который будет работать на сервере Linux.

Comment: Задам нескромный вопрос: а вы в гугл ходили? Что нашли сами по этому вопросу? Вопросы в стиле "просто напишите мне код, пожалуйста" здесь не очень любят.

Comment: Нескромно отвечу, что в тексте, что я написал выше и в помине нету ничего из серии: "Сделайте все за меня". Наоборот я хочу сам и спросил только модули которые мне в этом помогут или интересный материал на эту тему.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду, когда говорите "_`JSON.parse` не может получить данные по такой ссылке_"? Добавьте в вопрос кусок кода, в котором вы используете `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Для того, чтобы ответить на вопрос, совершенно необходим ваш код. Возможно, в нем мелкая ошибка. Возможно, совсем неверный подход. Или что-то еще. Без кода угадать невозможно.

Comment: Нафига писать в файл. И да, естественно, этот код не работает, потому что ты сначала читаешь, а потом пишешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Как разобрался так и написал. Сначала я записую в request, а потом читаю. Console.log показывает  { { [Object] ] } }.

Comment: До переоткрытия вопроса я всё равно не отвечу. Думай.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну если цель ваших "ответов" была сказать мне думать, то могли и не утруждать себя. Этим я собственно и занят.

Comment: Я же прямым текстом сказал, что ты сначала читаешь файл, а потом его пишешь. И здесь комментарии, а не ответы. Ответы ниже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за ваш комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

Нормальный json парсится безо всяких модулей при помощи `JSON.parse`, как и везде.

Если json не совсем нормальный и содержит js-комментарии, то их можно убрать с помощью модуля `strip-json-comments`.

Comment: Пример json-данных я указал. Они не измены.  Проблема возникла при получении данных в JSON.parse по ссылке типа http://site.com/base/?id=6767657657&key=klj87ui6789yi6789uy. при ее открытии на странице сразу структура json-файла

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю Node.js, но нагуглил:

```
var object_from_json = JSON.parse(string);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Моя вина и при правке текста случайно удалил про JSON.parse. В ней я столкнулся с тем, что не могу получить данные по ссылке вида http://site.com/base/?id=6767657657&key=klj87ui6789yi6789uy (как я указал выше). JSON.parse не может ее прочесть так как это не файл типа file.json

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = 'http://site.com/base/?id=6767657657&key=klj87ui6789yi6789uy';

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
    throw error || new Error("Invalid status code"); // Ну или что тут надо делать
  }

  var obj = JSON.parse(body);
  // ...
});
```